# fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory

Tags: 18.04, kernel

I get this when I'm compiling:

```
g++ test_box2p.cc -o test_box2p
```

or

```
CLANG++ test_box2p.cc -o test_box2p
```

or

```
C++ test_box2p.cc -o test_box2p
```

or

```
GCC test_box2p.cc -o test_box2p
```

Same error:

```
test_box2p.cc:24:10: fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory
 #include <config.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'test_box2p' failed
make: *** [test_box2p] Error 1
```

I'm under Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS 
kernel 4.15.0-38-generic

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439744/gtk-cant-find-config-h